# Extracting data from multiple Sharepoint to SQL database

Tags: sharepoint, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am trying to extract data from 2 sharepoint lists into sql database. One table is a list of Subjects and the other a list of Students. (It is a huge table but I've only taken a few values for your reference.)
What I've done so far is, only extract subjects with status-On Going.( So only codes 1001 and 1004 will be present in database.)
Now from the second list, I want to extract names of students only with the above subject codes.
How do I do it ?
[Table_Subjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edabl.png)
[Table_Students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StlQw.png)

Comment: Can you script the tables, please?

Comment: Sorry, I understand now that this is an Excel file, right?

Comment: Yes, I've added an excel file as example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to extract data from the SharePoint SQL server

```
use sharepoint
go
select * from [sharepoint].[YourSiteCollectionName].[YourListName]
where YourColumn = N'YourValue'
```

and easy to combine tsql query to join tables:

```
SELECT 
       [sharepoint].[YourSiteCollectionName].[subjects].code,
       [sharepoint].[YourSiteCollectionName].[students].name,
FROM
       [sharepoint].[YourSiteCollectionName].[students]

INNER JOIN 
       [sharepoint].[YourSiteCollectionName].[students]
ON     [sharepoint].[YourSiteCollectionName].[students].subjectCode
       =[sharepoint][YourSiteCollectionName].[subjects].code;
```